# Failing to send email via mutt using Ubuntu VirtualBox

Tags: email, mutt

[image]

The above screenshot shows the problem while trying to send an email

Comment: Is this VirtualBox VM running on your own computer at your home internet connection?

Comment: Yes VM is running on my own computer

Comment: @valiano Please refer to [this great tip on embedding images](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15566/480481).

Answer (score 1):

If you read the actual *response* you got, you'd know the problem is because your IP is not authorized to send mail directly to Google's servers.  In many cases, this is because it's a residential IP address or otherwise blacklisted and requires you to use the mail relay provided by your ISP, or by having the system submit the email to another server that is permitted to deliver (this is called a 'mail relay').

You could have found this yourself by actually reading the response from Google, in the message itself, which is this part:

```
<[SNIPPED]@gmail.com>: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.200.26] said:
    550-5.7.1 [183.82.212.36] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized 
    to send email directly to our servers.  Please use the SMTP relay at your 
    service provider instead. Learn more at 
    https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NotAuthorizedError
```

You can read up *more* about this response by [going to the link that the Undeliverable response actually provides you](https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NotAuthorizedError).

To fix this, you either need to use an email relay provided by your ISP, or set up a mail relay externally and configure your local PostFix instance (which is actually the MTA, which we determine by those headers down there of `X-Postfix-`) to relay through the external mail server instead of directly sending from your home Internet or the Internet that the VBox VM is running on.

Comment: Thank You @thomas.I understood the problem. But Iam really unaware about the procedure of setting mail relay.

Comment: @Lasyaartham there are multiple descriptions online of how to setup a closed mail relay for your own needs, however you'll need an external server or such.  Alternatively, sing up for a GMail account or some other account and set up Postfix to relay the data through that GMail account instead (a little more tricky to get working but it would work)